# Prove $F$ is a continuous function of $r$ or not?

Tags: calculus, piecewise-continuity

I have this one problem in my Calculus 1 assignment that I'd like to ask.
The gravitational force exerted by the planet Earth on a unit mass at a distance $r$ from the center of the planet is
$$F(r) = \begin{cases} \frac{GMr}{R^3} & r < R \\ \frac{GM}{r^2} & r \ge R \end{cases}$$

where $M$ is the mass of Earth, $R$ is its radius, and $G$ is the gravitational constant. Is $F$ a
continuous function of $r$?
I have no idea where to start and I'm completely stuck here.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Can you see that $F(r)$ is continuous for $0<r<R$ and for $r>R$? Can you show that it is continuous at $r=R$ as well?

Comment: Are you familiar with Delta epsilon proofs?

Comment: @TurlocTheRed Nope, I'm completely unfamiliar with that.

Comment: They follow directly from Gauss law for gravity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**: Since both pieces of the piecewise function are continuous functions in their respective domains of definition, it is just required that the continuity be checked at the point $r=R$, which would be done by checking for the following conditions:

- $\lim_{r\to R} F(r)$ exists
- $F(r=R)$ exists
- $F(r=R)=\lim_{r\to R} = F(r)$

Comment: Thank you so much for your hint! Now I can solve this question :)